# why do i get 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value' error on mongodb while sending network request?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, social-networking, mern

I am trying to make an social networking website where i want to integrate follower suggestion. So i have send network request to the backend with an array of user id.

the backend request.body contains this array `"following": ["608b05477eeba243c5ac8bcb","608b05477eeba243c5ac8bcc"]`

I want all of the users from database except those id in the **following** array. I have written this query on my backend

```
userRouter.post(
  "/suggestions",
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.following);
    const suggestedUsers = await User.find({
      _id: { $ne: req.body.following },
    });

    res.send(suggestedUsers);
  })
);
```

But whenever i send the request from **postman** , i get this error

```
{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ '608b05477eeba243c5ac8bcb', '608b05477eeba243c5ac8bcc' ]\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""
}
```

My userModel.js looks like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    emailAddress: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }],
    followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true }],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

Here is my User database Record
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're trying to check that its not in an array of ids and as such you should use `$nin`(not in) instead of `$ne` (not equal)

```
_id: { $nin: req.body.following },
```